# Get dateTime from weekday

Tags: python, datetime

I'm scraping data from a website and I would like to know when this data are updated. But on the site there is not an absolute data, only a reference like this: Updated on Monday 21:00 or this one, Update 1 day ago. Anyone can help me to get the timestamp from these strings? Thanks

Comment: What input u have and what output u expect?

Comment: @Lafada I have in input strings like: Updated on Monday 21:00 or Updated 1 day ago and I would like to transform these strings in 23/11/2015 21:00

Comment: consider checking - https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime

Comment: @TomRon This library is perfect for my job. Thanks a lot TomRon!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`parsedatetime` module](https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime) as [@Tom Ron suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018414/get-datetime-from-weekday#comment55792386_34018414):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import parsedatetime as ptd

ptc = ptd.Constants()
ptc.YearParseStyle = 0 # avoid future year
ptc.DOWParseStyle = 0 # how weekday is parsed
cal = ptd.Calendar(ptc)
for human_time in ["Updated on Monday 21:00", "1 day ago"]:
    print(cal.parseDT(human_time)[0])
```

#### Output

```
2015-11-30 21:00:00
2015-11-30 20:49:03
```